# Vim and python - jump to definition key binding

Tags: python, vim

The [following youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YhqsjUUHj6g&t=27m57s) shows that it is possible to jump to definition using vim for python.

However when I try the same shortcut (Ctrl-G) it doesnt work...
How is it possible to perform the same "jump to definition"?

I installed the plugin Ctrl-P but not rope.

Comment: that would require `ctags` installed and ctags enabled in vim.

Answer (score 7):

This does not directly answer your question but provides a better alternative.  I use [JEDI](http://jedi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) with VIM, as a static code analyser, it offers far better options than ctags. I use the spacemacs key-binding in vim so with localleader set to ','

```
" jedi
let g:jedi#use_tabs_not_buffers = 0  " use buffers instead of tabs
let g:jedi#show_call_signatures = "1"
let g:jedi#goto_command = "<localleader>gt"
let g:jedi#goto_assignments_command = "<localleader>ga"
let g:jedi#goto_definitions_command = "<localleader>gg"
let g:jedi#documentation_command = "K"
let g:jedi#usages_command = "<localleader>u"
let g:jedi#completions_command = "<C-Space>"
let g:jedi#rename_command = "<leader>r"
```

Answer (score 4):

Vim's code navigation is based on a universal database called *tags file*. It needs to be generated (and updated) manually. `:help ctags` lists some applications that can do that. *Exuberant ctags* is a common one that supports many programming languages, but there are also specialized ones, like `ptags.py` (found in your Python source directory at `Tools/scripts/ptags.py`).

Plugins like [easytags.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3114) provide more convenience by e.g. automatically updating the tags file on each save.

The default command for jumping to the definition is `CTRL-]` (not `CTRL-G`; that prints the current filename; see `:help CTRL-G`), or the Ex command `:tag {identifier}`; see all at `:help tag-commands`.

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions for people reading other answers to this question in the future:

- tags file has one limitation. If in your code multiple objects has the same name you will have problem using ctrl-] as it will jump to first one and not necessary correct one. In this situation you can use g ctrl-] (or :tjump command or :tselect command) to get selection list. Potentially you want to map ctrl-] to "g ctrl-]"
- It is possible that you want to have possibility to jump to correct object. In that case you might want to use jedi vim and if you are used to c-] you might want to use this mapping for jedi goto let g:jedi#goto_command = ""
- Lastly you want to use universal ctags instead of excuberant ctags because of better new files support (not necessary python).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using YouCompleteMe there is a command for that

```
:YcmCompleter GoToDefinition
```

if you want to add a shortcut for doing that in a new tab

```
nnoremap <leader>d :tab split \| YcmCompleter GoToDefinition<CR>
```